# how to set ILArray<fcomplex>2D matrix to specific value?

Tags: c#, matlab, ilnumerics

the code as following:

```
 ILLogical isevanescent = abs(f) / abs(kx) < c;
 SIGk[isevanescent] = new fcomplex(0, 0);
```

where SIGk is ILArray type with 2D size,and isevanescent is ILLogical type with tha same size. I want to set SIGk element to zero when isevanescent element value is 1; but here is an error
“resizing array via sequential index access is supported for empty, scalar or vector only”

in matlatb, the working code is  ：

```
isevanescent = abs(f)./abs(kx)<c;
SIGk(isevanescent) = 0;
```

is here something wrong in my code ?

Comment: What size is `isevanescent`? What `SIGk`?

Comment: thank your caution. i check my code again,and find an error, and it work now